# Detailed Pandas Dataframe manipulation setting columns as index, column names, with remaining data in newly structured DF

Tags: python, pandas, transformation

I have Python / Mesa Agent Based Model which simulates evacuation scenarios with malevolent actors blocking exits and capture repeated run data which looks like this:

[image: Example data]

I want to make the several changes, the first of which is index by RunId (which range from 0 - 74). I've done so with `df = df.set_index('RunId')`

However, the following manipulations are where I'm struggling:

- The maximum number of model steps, 0 - X (174 in this case) as column names
- The number of agents remaining to evacuate (Agents column) as the data entry (note, not every run will have entries to the maximum number of steps)
- A column as the end with the malevolent entry for a given RunId row entry

This way a given row contains all the data for a given run: agents remaining per step and the number of malevolent entities for that run. As I understand things this should feed XGBoost better. Final result would look like the following:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because the data you gave didn't have data for `RunId`, I used a data that looked like this.

```
data = [[0, 0, 322, 0],
[0, 1, 316, 0],
[0, 2, 313, 0],
[0, 3, 311, 0],
[0, 4, 307, 0],
[1, 0, 321, 1],
[1, 1, 315, 1],
[1, 2, 311, 1],
[1, 3, 308, 1],
[1, 4, 304, 1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["RunId", "Step", "Agents", "Malevolent"])
```

---

I suppose the `malevolent` column would have the sum of all malevolent values for each `RunId`

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("RunId")
groups = []
for group in df["RunId"].unique():
  group_df = grouped_df.get_group(group).iloc[:, 1:3]
  group_df = group_df.set_index(group_df["Step"].values).T.reset_index(drop = True).iloc[1:]
  malevolent = grouped_df.get_group(group)["Malevolent"].sum()
  group_df.insert(column = "RunId", loc = 0, value = [group])
  group_df.insert(column = "Malevolent", loc = group_df.shape[1], value = [malevolent])
  groups.append(group_df)

final_df = pd.concat(groups).set_index("RunId")
```

Output -

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | Malevolent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 322 | 316 | 313 | 311 | 307 | 0 |
| 1 | 321 | 315 | 311 | 308 | 304 | 5 |

This gets the output, but I would really appreciate some suggestions to make this code more efficient in the comments!

Comment: Thank you so much! I need to stare at this for a while to try and better understand why the manipulations are working as they are, but in the end I have what I need. Thanks again. :-)

Comment: For the explaination part, I firstly group the dataframe on the basis of `RunId`, get the columns `Steps` and `Agents`. Then I set the index of the column to the values of `Step` and do a tranpose on the dataframe. This way I have steps as the columns and agents as the value of that column. Then I calculate the malevolent by just summing the values for each row of the grouped data and add it as the column.